# Creating a table of dates from a database

Tags: php, mysql

Before I begin I'm not asking for a solution - as I'm trying to learn I'm just looking for some pointers so I can work it out myself.

I'm currently learning php and mysql, and have been given the task of creating a resource booking table and form. A form places a name, resource, start and end date into a database, and then this needs to be extracted and displayed as a table on a web page, so users can see if there is a meeting already booked at their desired time.

Final product mockup:
[image: Final product]

Here is the database table I made in phpmyadmin (called "meetings"):
[image: Meetings Table]

I've written a while loop to loop through hours (from 8:00 to 19:00). This works left to right not up and down, so when checking if a meeting is already booked I'll have to search for 8:00 monday, then 8:00 tuesday etc:

```
$i = 8;
while($i < 20)
{
    echo    "<tr>".
            "<td>".$i.":00</td>".
            "<td></td>".
            "<td></td>".
            "<td></td>".
            "<td></td>".
            "<td></td>".
            "<td></td>".
            "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

and I've started a function "isMeeting" but I have no idea where to go from here

```
function isMeeting()
    {
        $query= "SELECT * FROM meetings"; //WHERE hour part of start datetime field is $hour?
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        }
    }
```

What would be my next steps to populating the table?

Comment: Will the while loop stops? It doesn't look like it will stop because you used $i++ instead of $hour++

Comment: Ohh, I changed it all to $i on my laptop but forgot to change them all on here. I'll fix that

Comment: Just hints: You're using a function to determine if there is a meeting, make that function accept a parameter (for the hour you want to check) and then look at mySQL WHERE clause to find any meetings (rows) that have a start time earlier or equal and an end time later or equal (based on the hour parameter) to determine if there is a meeting for that hour.

Comment: If you're starting to learn it, learn it the better way. Take a look at `pdo` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql` extension.

Comment: @Matt.C Can you see why http://pastebin.com/x6Gp7xqU is returning a "y" for all the days and hours? (I haven't worked in months, yet)

Comment: your function will always return "y" (what's wrong with a boolean value by the way?) you need to check the mySQL result, perhaps with num_rows() and return true is it's a meeting and false if it isn't, don't use die() to control your flow.

Comment: @Matt.C Nothings wrong with bools, it's just I know in future I'm likely to be returning a string (the bookers name).

I just realised what an incredibly silly mistake I made.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I'm learning PDO at the moment, but as I need to push this to the intranet ASAP and I know more MySQL at this point in time, I'm using that now and switching later to PDO when I know how.